# Parse a string that contains data bindings in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a backend rendered template that returns a JSON object that contains a string that needs some dynamic data bindings for example...

```
sampleLogic = {
  "1": "Sample static text and some {{ dynamic_text }}." 
}
```

By default the string is escaped, what's the best way in angular to convert dynamic_text to bind to $scope.dynamic_text?

JS:

```
 var sampleLogic = {
    "1": "Sample static text and some {{ dynamic_text }}."
};

function parseMe($scope) {
    $scope.copy = sampleLogic['1'];
    $scope.dynamic_text = "dynamic text woooot";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="parseMe">
        <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="copy"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RzPM3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [$interpolate](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24interpolate) module and easily achieve it like this

```
var dynamic_text = {
    'dynamic_text': "dynamic text woooot"
};
$scope.copy = $interpolate(sampleLogic['1'])(dynamic_text);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T4SRk/)**</kbd>