# Angular.js's $compile doesn't replace values

Tags: angularjs

I'm build an Angular.js app that uses a third-party library. The library requires me to pass in a string containing HTML. This HTML is complex and requires several values to be injected. I'd like to use Angular's build in `$compile` service to compile that data. Here's an example:

```
// create the template
var template = "<p>{{ test }}</p>";

// set up the scope
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
scope.test = "hello";

// compile the template
var htmlString = $compile(template)(scope)[0].outerHTML;
```

When I run this code, I would expect `htmlString` to be `<p>hello</p>`, but instead it's `<p class="ng-scope ng-binding">{{ test }}</p>`. I understand Angular is setting up its bindings, but I want static content. Is there any way to achieve the behavior I want?

Comment: Try $interpolate http://stackoverflow.com/a/18317633/304319

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As sza said, the solution is easy thanks to the $interpolate function:

```
var template = 'Hello {{ name }}';
console.log($interpolate(template)({name: 'World'}));
```

Console output is:

```
Hello World
```