# AngularJS - rendering nested scope vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, templates, web

Given the following code (simplified for the question):

```
var app = angular.module("app", []).controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.data = {
    query: "",
    rnd: Math.random(),
    en: "this is your query: {{data.query}} and ({{rnd}}) is the random number",
    es: "esta es tu consulta: {{data.query}} Y ({{rnd}}) es el número aleatorio"
}
});
```

and the following view:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="data.query">
    <div>Desired results EN : this is your query: {{data.query}} and ({{data.rnd}}) is the random number</div>
    <div>Desired results ES : esta es tu consulta: {{data.query}} Y ({{data.rnd}}) es el número aleatorio</div>
    <hr>
    <div>{{data.en}}</div>
    <div>{{data.es}}</div>
</div>
```

**Q**: *What is the right way to render a nested value?*

**Update**: just to clarify, I'm trying to create a language dictionary to my app, some of the captions contains scope vars, and I would like to keep the dictionary structures like this:

{key : sentenceWithVars}

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zBR3g/14/)**

Comment: Thanks to @basilikum :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317307/parse-a-string-that-contains-data-bindings-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create two different bindings:

JS

```
var app = angular.module("app", []).controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        query: "",
        en: "this is your query: ",
        es: "esta es tu consulta: "
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="data.query">
    <div>Current Query:{{data.query}}</div>
    <div>{{data.en}}{{data.query}}</div>
    <div>{{data.es}}{{data.query}}</div>
</div>
```

Or watch `query` and update `en` and `es` accordingly:

JS

```
var app = angular.module("app", []).controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        query: "",
        en: "this is your query: ",
        es: "esta es tu consulta: "
    }
    $scope.$watch("data.query", function (value) {
        $scope.data.en = "this is your query: " + value;
        $scope.data.es = "esta es tu consulta: " + value;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="data.query">
    <div>Current Query:{{data.query}}</div>
    <div>{{data.en}}</div>
    <div>{{data.es}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This example is just simplified, think of a language pack containing many templates like "some text {{val1}} and {{val2}}" in many languages. when translating you would like to keep your dictionary as key:sentence where sentence can contain many scope values

Comment: In this case have a look at the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317307/parse-a-string-that-contains-data-bindings-in-angularjs Maybe that helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I just found the same solution :)